# How to ignore Windows "Debug Error!" dialogs in automated tests

Tags: windows, debugging, automated-tests

I have a test suite that runs a Windows executable with a variety of command line options to test that the executable works correctly. In some test cases, those arguments cause the executable to break badly and this dialog appears:

[image]

Unfortunately, this dialog remains until I manually press **Abort**, **Retry**, or **Ignore**. This prevents me from running these tests in an automated fashion. I have tried calling the executable through the Windows CDB Debugger with a variety of CDB options with no luck.

How can I prevent these dialogs from appearing or automatically continue on with the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear from the window title that you are testing the Debug build of the program.  This is not a good practice, you are not testing the program the way it is going to run on your customer's machine.  A Debug build is suitable for the programmer to debug their code.  But it does occasionally *hide* a bug.  Such bugs can be very hard to diagnose, you need tests to flush them out.  You are not performing such a test.

Only test the Release build.  Which then also automatically solves this dialog problem, the Release version of the CRT doesn't display it.

Btw: test failed.

Comment: Nice work catching that I was testing a Debug executable... I hadn't realized that they would work in a noticeably different way. As soon as I started testing the Release executables, I started getting the normal "Windows Error Reporting" dialogs that I can catch and ignore by wrapping the executable in CDB. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [the Microsoft C Runtime Library manual page on `abort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0.aspx), this message box is expected when you link to the debug version of the Microsoft CRT. You can link to the release CRT to avoid the message, but instead Windows will trap the crash (as abort() is considered to be a program crash by the CRT) and you would see a Windows Error Reporting message instead.

The manual page also says that you can disable the message box in code using [the Microsoft-extension `_set_abort_behavior()` function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e631wekh.aspx) If you go that route, you might want to have some way to control whether the message is enabled, using command-line switches or something similar.